# Rails i18n validation on inputs (not error messages)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, internationalization

I'm writing an app that must be able to accept more than just the English alphabet.

Everything I search for points me to error validation messages, which I already have set up for translation; that's no problem.

Does anyone know of a resource in ruby/rails that defines acceptable alphabets by language/region/country?

Answer (score 0):

Rails accepts all characters. In your code, you must to add "# encoding: UTF-8" at the top of your ruby files.

Comment: I'm accepting i18n data just fine.  I store it in the database great.  I'm looking for something along the lines of what goes after validate_format_of :last_name, etc...

Comment: You want to accept all characters in all cases? A standard regular expression should work. Could you give an example of what should be valid and what should not?